# How to show that these 2 sets are dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory

I'm looking at the following two sets and want to know how one would go about proving that they are both dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (note that $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b$ isn't divisible by $p$):
$$S^+(a,b) = \{m\in\mathbb{Z}\mid m\equiv a \pmod b \text{ and } m>0\}$$
$$S^-(a,b) = \{m\in\mathbb{Z}\mid m\equiv a \pmod b \text{ and } m<0\}$$

Comment: Fixed, thanks! Sorry about that

Comment: The sets are just defined like that and I want to prove that they are dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: I specified that b isn't divisible by p

Comment: Note that translations are homeomorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}_p$, thus you can reduce to the case $a=0$. Furthermore, you can make an element positive or negative by looking at $m\pm p^k$ for large $k$ (this is arbitrary close to $m$ in the $p$-norm).

Comment: As $b$ is not divisible by $p$, we get that $p^k \not\equiv 0$ mod $p$ for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Thus, there exists $k \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ such that $p^k \equiv 1$ mod $p$. Now consider $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. We want to show that it is in the closure of $S^+(a,b)$. If $x\equiv a$ mod $p$, we are done. Otherwise, note that $x\pm (a-x)p^{kN} \in S^+(a,b)$ (with the correct choice of the sign). This proves that $\mathbb{Z}$ is in the closure of $S^+(a,b)$. Then recall that $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, hence, we are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will show that $S^+(a,b)$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, the same ideas apply for $S^-(a,b)$.

As $b$ is not divisible by $p$, we get that $p^k \not\equiv 0$ mod $p$ for any $k\in \mathbb{N}$ (otherwise, $b$ would divide $p^k$ and hence, $p$ would divide $b$ which we assumed not to be the case). In fact, as $p,b$ are coprime, we get that $p$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$. As the units of $\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ are finite, we get by the pigeon hole principle that there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ such that $p^N \equiv 1$ mod $b$.

Now we show that $S^+(a,b)$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}$ in the $p$-adic metric. The claim follows then from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. We want to show that $x$ is in the $p$-adic closure of $S^+(a,b)$. If $x\in S^+(a,b)$, then this is trivial. On the other hand, if $x\notin S^+(a,b)$, we consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with

$$ x_n = x + (\tilde{a}-x) p^{nN}, $$

where $\tilde{a} = a + mb$ and $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ is such that $\tilde{a}>x$. For sufficiently large $n$ we have that $x_n >0$ (because $\tilde{a}-x>0$). Furthermore, we have

$$ x_n \equiv x + (\tilde{a}-x) \equiv a \quad \text{mod } b, $$

where we used $\tilde{a} \equiv a$ mod $b$ and $p^N \equiv 1$ mod $b$. Thus, for $n$ sufficiently large we get $x_n \in S^+(a,b)$. Additionally, we have

$$ \Vert x_n - x \Vert_p = \Vert (\tilde{a}-x) p^{nN}\Vert_p \leq \Vert p^{nN} \Vert_p = \frac{1}{p^{nN}} \rightarrow 0 $$

for $n\rightarrow \infty$. This implies that $x$ is in the $p$-adic closure of $S^+(a,b)$.

In order to get the density of $S^-(a,b)$ one just needs to change the choice of $\tilde{a}$, namely, choose $m$ such that $\tilde{a}-x<0$ and the very same argument goes through.